# How to insert Timestamp Data when using dojox.charting.Chart2D

Tags: dojox.charting

I am using dojox.charting.Chart2D to display Graphs/ Charts in our Application .

My Timestamp data would be in this format 2005-06-29 08:05:00 .

I am using dojox.charting.Chart2D to display Charts .

Could anybody please let me know how to insert this TimeStamp Data into the addSeries Method of Chart2D ??

Or please let me know what is the appropiate way for inserting Timestamp Data into DOJO Charts ??

help  me , my work has been struck .

Answer (score 2):

I would do this on the server side following Dojox's [addSeries](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/charting.html) method. I would assume you are wanting to plot an array of timestamps, otherwise there would be only one point on the chart.  You could do something like this:

```
chart1.addSeries(
    "Series 1",
    [
        // Your server code here
        // series is an array of times
        foreach($series as $v) {
            echo date("Y-m-d : H:i:s", $v).", ";
        }
        // End server code
    ]
);
```